# I have to extract data from a Colum in a dataset by month

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BvXp.png)these month's data I have to retrieve from the dataset
total number of new cases in China and India for March 2020, September 2020, March 2021, September 2021, March 2022 and September 2022

I want to get all the month data into a new data frame, I tried with data. Frame but it didn't help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What did you try? What errors did you get exactly?

Comment: I tried with few of them, I'll try to explain you the problem first. For eg: You have a dataset of an entire year with everyday entry in it. I want to retrieve only data of march from that entire data set.

Comment: Please check the image i have just added for more information about the dataset @MrFlick

Comment: Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064). See the link I previously provided on including a reproducible example in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the picture I cannot see what format your date string has. Assuming it is a Date variable (`as.Date()`), you can subset as follows:

```
start <- as.Date("2020-03-01")
end <- as.Date("2020-03-31")

subset <- covidData[which(covidData$date >= start & covidData$date <= end),]
```

This won't work, if the date column contains just characters.
In this case, first convert the column:

```
covidData$date <- as.Date(covidData$date)
```